# Expose TypeScript variable to JS global scope (with webpack)

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I'm using webpack to compile my TypeScript to Javascript and I want to expose a variable to the global scope so others can access it.

I know how to do the following in TypeScript

```js
window["MyVariable"] = 'Hello';
```

and read it in JavaScript like that

```js
console.log(window.MyVariable);
```

But I'd prefer if I could just have it in the global scope like that.

```js
console.log(MyVariable);
```

Is this possible?

Best regards,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever exists on the global scope can be accessed without `window.` in JavaScript. So if you set `window['MyVariable'] = 'Hello'`, you can access it in JavaScript simply with `MyVariable`.

Comment: but not in typescript?

Comment: @JonasWilms, I don't think you can access `MyVariable` from this scenario in TypeScript the same way you can in JavaScript, without typing. But if you declare it, the type checker should not complain.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can do this; TS just adds type safety (and does some transpilation depending on the target ES version).

Since `window` is the global object in the browser, adding members to it makes them available globally.

Depending on the strictness settings (e.g. disallow implicit `any`) you might get a compiler error, but that is simple to work around:

```
(window as any).MyVariable = 'Hello';
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply Lucero, I didn't know that! Works fine thanks!